# Number of ways to create "trios" from the numbers $1{-}20$

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say you have the numbers $1{-}20$: $$1,2,3,4....19,20$$
and you need to create *trios* (combinations of three different numbers, order ignored). How many different ways can you arrange these numbers?

For example, I can have: $1{-}2{-}3$, $1{-}2{-}19$, $2{-}19{-}20$. I could probably list them all but it would take me an extremely long time, I'm looking for a more systematic way.

Any ideas?

I was looking around the internet, and it turns out that $20!$ would give me the number of ways all of them can be arranged, for example:

- $1,2,3,4....19,20$,
- $2,3,1,4....19,20$,
- $20,3,2,,4....19$.

But I'm looking for something different.

Comment: First, you choose 3 things from those 20 things. Then, you arrange those 3 things.

Comment: You have 20 items and you need to choose 3 of them. You also need to determine whether the order matters (i.e. is (1,2,3) the same as (3,2,1) or are you counting them as two separate arrangements). You can use $\binom{20}{3}$ if you know what that notation means. If you don't know then maybe start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Comment: order doesn't matter, so (1,2,3) is the same as (3,2,1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of three objects chosen out of twenty.  One notation for this is $20 \choose 3$.  If you imagine choosing them in order, you have $20$ choices for the first, $19$ for the second, and $18$ for the third, but you have counted each combination six times, because there are $3!=6$ orders that you could have chosen them in.  The final answer is then $\frac{20\cdot 19 \cdot 18}{3!}=\frac {20!}{3!(20-3)!}=1140$

Comment: If you search on the tags combinatorics, combinations, permutations you will find many worked examples in this area.